# ordinal_position values in information_schema.columns out of sequence

Tags: postgresql

When I run the following SQL to list the columns for `base.mytable`:

```
select column_name, ordinal_position, is_nullable, data_type 
from information_schema.columns
where table_catalog = 'mycatalog'
and table_schema = 'base'
and table_name = 'mytable'
order by ordinal_position;
```

I get the `ordinal_position` column values out of sequence:

```
1
2
3
4
5
9
24
25
26
27
28
29
31
32
33
34
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
```

I would expect them to all be in sequence and incremented by 1.

Can anybody explain why this is the case?

Comment: You probably dropped some columns hence the gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That field states as the DOCS says `Ordinal position of the column within the table (count starts at 1)` Which means that it is the creation order but it not say anything about changes you've made on that table. So every change as `drop column` will not affect (reorder) that increment ordinal_name

Here is just the creation statement

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/02bfb/1

Now the same creation with an alter table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f6551/1

Answer (score 1):

Dropping columns will do it. Also, table inheritance can cause funky things to happen with the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

except the method of recreating the table or columns, you can just to change SQL with:
row_number() over(order by ordinal_position)