# How to get the normal order of table by select column_name (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, select

Helo, i have a simple problem, but can't find a solution.
I have created a new table from pgAdmin4 with 21 columns. When i use the query editor and i use the sql command: **SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1'**, i get the 21 columns but not in the normal order but in a random order. How i get the order in which i create the table? When i use this command by Microsoft SQL i get the correct order.

Example
Columns: ID, one, two ,three, four, five

Output: One, four, five, ID, two, three

Comment: Because **there is no order**. (not for rows, not for column(name)s)

Comment: yes, but how i get the sequence in which i create the table. I need the order in which I created the table in my programme.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to remember that. The DBMS does not remember it for you.

Comment: I dont understand why by Microsoft SQL i get the correct sequence, but not in postgres SQL. It is the same command and the same table.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) there is a `ordinal_position` column in table `information_schema.columns`.

So just order by `ordinal_position`:

```sql
SELECT
  column_name 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns 
WHERE 
  table_name = 'table1'
ORDER BY 
  ordinal_position
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I need

Comment: @MauriceMertes  It would be kind and proper then to accept the answer.

Comment: Are you sure the order is stable, even after `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: @wildplasser : The documentation says nothing about it. I see no reason why the order should change when altering a column but I am not sure it doesn't. The gaps in position are possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708572/ordinal-position-values-in-information-schema-columns-out-of-sequence

Comment: @wildplasser: yes because `ordinal_position` is not affected by an alter table (and if a new column is added, it's added "at the end")